Where does the complex conjugate term generally come from in a Hamiltonian?
I find myself stumbling across Hamiltonians which go like
$$
\hat{H}\sim\alpha\hat{a}+\alpha^*\hat{a}^\dagger
$$
How does this form of Hamiltonian actually come about?
To my knowledge, the Hamiltonian describing a given physical process may be obtained by quantizing the corresponding classical interaction. For example, one may obtain the Hamiltonian for a dipole interaction starting from the knowledge that the energy of an electric dipole $\vec{d}$ in an electric field $\vec{E}$ is given by $\vec{E}\cdot\vec{d}$. Is there an analogous physical understanding I can use to come at the form of the Hamiltonian above? Or is this way of thinking about it incorrect after all?

The simplest justification is probably that the Hamiltonian has to be Hermitian. After all, its eigenvalues are interpreted as the possible energies of the system, and hence they need to be real. This is equivalent to asking for the Hamiltonian to be Hermitian. Hence, one cannot add a non-Hermitian term without also adding its Hermitian conjugate.

This type of Hamiltonian is a second quantisation one. The most important part is defining your operators $a$ and $a^\dagger$. For example, if you have two interacting dipoles the interaction energy would be :
$$
H_{int} = \frac{1}{r_{ij}^3}\big{[}\mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{d}_j - 3 (\mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{n}_{ij})(\mathbf{d}_j\cdot\mathbf{n}_{ij})\big{]} \hspace{2cm}\text{(1)}
$$
for dipoles at sites $i,j$ separated by a distance $r_{ij}$. If you define your ladder operators as :
$$
a_{i,\sigma} = \sqrt{\frac{M\omega_0}{2\hbar}} \mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}} + i \frac{\mathbf{p}_i\cdot\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}}{\sqrt{2\hbar M\omega_0}}\\
a_{i,\sigma}^\dagger = \sqrt{\frac{M\omega_0}{2\hbar}} \mathbf{d}_i\cdot\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}} - i \frac{\mathbf{p}_i\cdot\mathbf{\hat{\sigma}}}{\sqrt{2\hbar M\omega_0}}
$$
Where I used $\hat{\sigma}$ as the unitary vectors along ${x,y,z}$. Then you express the dipoles as a combination of your operators $a, a^\dagger$. And finally use these expressions in (1), you will end up with a hamiltonian of the form:
$$
H_{int} = \sum_\sigma B_\sigma (a_{i,\sigma} + a^\dagger_{i,\sigma})(a_{j,\sigma} + a^\dagger_{j,\sigma})
$$
Which is the interaction hamiltonian (1) expressed in terms of the new operators $a_{i,\sigma}$. The prefactor $B_\sigma$ comes naturally.
The complex conjugate part in your examples should derive directly from the definition of your operators $\hat{a}, \hat{a}^\dagger$.
